# Android NDK native libraries and documentation

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I started working on the NDK - Native Development Kit using JNI.

From my understanding the NDK contains: 
**1.** The source code containing a set of .so libraries (and c/c++ header files), each specifically compiled to different Android Architecture: such as arm, mips, x86. which supply us some c/c++ APIs to the Android device.
**2.** The tool chain which is responsible for the build for each Android architecture.

**Example of working with the NDK:**

I am using in my app, the logcat in c++ code, for this I added to my Android.mk (in Android studios - the gradle properties):

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

And in my c++ code I include the header:

```
#include <android/log.h>
```

And I do see the header file in:
\platforms\android-21\arch-arm\usr\include\android\log.h
and the lib file in:
\platforms\android-21\arch-arm\usr\lib\liblog.so

**My questions:**

1. Not all APIs that exist in the Java SDK framework exist in the NDK Framework, right?
2. If I"m right about 1: While it seems very easy to work with the log, how do I know which APIs are supported and which are not?
   For example, is there a lib for using the camera/flashlight/gps/Writing to storage or for these I have to use Java code?
   I have not seen a clear API or documantation about it, not in the http://developer.android official, and not in the docs provided in the NDK installation (the stableAPIs.html contains minimal description for minimal API set), and not in the many StackOverFlow questions I read.
3. This is on a different subject, The NDK compiler for the android different architectures is based on GCC to compile our c++ code right? and how do I know which c++ version am I using?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right.
2. In your NDK directory, go to `docs`, open `Start_Here.html`, then click on `Stable APIs` for a list of APIs supported by the NDK. Note that you can call the Java APIs from C++ code through the Java Native Interface (JNI), but that's a separate topic (and slightly more advanced).
3. There are both GCC and Clang/LLVM toolchains included with the NDK.
   By C++ version, do you actually mean *compiler version*? If you mean compiler version, then you can specify which one you want to be used if you require a specific version:

   `# Specify that you want GCC 4.8 to be used. This goes in your Application.mk file
   NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8`

If you really meant C++ version, then unless you explictly specified a standard (e.g. with `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++1y`) you're probably getting the C++98 standard (possibly with some extensions).

Comment: Thanks for you comment! :) this answer my questions.
just regarding to question 2, I already saw the Stable APIs section in the html but it seems very poor.
For example, I would like now to work natively with sensors,
and in the Stable APIs there is just a 1 liner on it:
"
<android/sensor.h> To Listen to input events and sensors directly from native code.
"
so now I have to explicitly go to the header file to try to understand.
And if I would want documentation about the libraries and their APIs it seems non existence.
Isn't there any other document?

Comment: You can take a look at the `native-activity` sample program that comes with the NDK. It uses the accelerometer.

Comment: Yup, but I am not specifically intrestted in the sensor implementation, it was just as an example...
I am accepting your answer so thanks :)
I wanted to create a separate post but maybe you know why can't I get auto complete to work when writing c++ code for these native APIs methods in AndroidStudios?

Comment: Well, the NDK documentation isn't all that great. The sample programs and the headers are mostly what you've got to go by. But for some of the APIs you can find documentation elsewhere (e.g. khronos.org has documentation for OpenGL ES and OpenSL ES). As for the Android Studio issue; I don't use Android Studio myself so I don't know how to configure it.